# Find Mersenne prime numbers using list comprehensions and my code

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, primes

I wrote this code to find prime numbers, but how could I change it to find Mersenne prime numbers?

```
def prime_test_list(n,known_primes):
k = 1
stop_val = len(known_primes)
if(n>2):
    while k<stop_val:
        cprime = known_primes[k]
        if n%cprime == 0:
            return 0            
        else:
            k+=1
    return 1
else:
    return 1

def prime_print_list(a):
    n = 2
    known_primes = [1] 
    while(n<a):
        val = prime_test_list(n,known_primes)
        if(val==1):
            known_primes.append(n)            
        n+=1
    print known_primes
```

Comment: `set(format(n, 'b')) == {'1'}`

Comment: what you mean??

Comment: my function above will print prime numbers. so for example prime_print_list(20) is 1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19), but mersenne prime does not include 5,11,13,..

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
def mersenne_test(n):

    k = 0
    m = 0
    while m<=n:
        m = 2**k-1
        if(n==m):
            return "This number is a Mersenne number since it is equal by to 2**%d-1" % k
        k += 1
    return "This number is not a Mersenne number."
```

Comment: am trying to find the mersenne prime numbers. I believe they are 49

Comment: @user59220 hm ... that's not a matter of belief you should check that

Comment: my question is how to print out mersenne prime numbers, which i believe they are 49

Answer (score 0):

We can use your prime code as ***part*** of finding Mersenee primes.  First step, clean up your code:

```
def prime_test_list(n, known_primes):
    if n < 2:
        return False

    if n % 2 == 0:
        return n == 2  # 2 is the only even prime

    k = 0

    while known_primes[k] ** 2 <= n:

        if n % known_primes[k] == 0:
            return False

        k += 1

    return True

def prime_print_list(a):
    known_primes = [2]

    for n in range(3, a, 2):
        if prime_test_list(n, known_primes):
            known_primes.append(n)

    return known_primes

print(prime_print_list(100))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

The `prime_print_list(n)` function returns all the primes less than `n`.  Now we need to add one function and extend `prime_print_list()`.  I'm using Python 3, but it should work in Python 2.

The function we need to add is a [Lucas-Lehmer primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test) which we call after we've used our existing `prime_test_list()` function to check an exponent for primeness.

We'll extend `prime_print_list()` to become `mersenne_prime_print_list(()` by letting it do what it did, but then perform the above test and keep track of positive results in a separate list:

```
def lucas_lehmer_test(p, m):
    s = 4

    for _ in range(p - 2):
        s = ((s * s) - 2) % m

    return s == 0

def prime_test_list(n, known_primes):
    if n < 2:
        return False

    if n % 2 == 0:
        return n == 2  # 2 is the only even prime

    k = 0

    while known_primes[k] ** 2 <= n:

        if n % known_primes[k] == 0:
            return False

        k += 1

    return True

def mersenne_prime_print_list(a):
    known_primes = [2]
    known_mersenne_primes = [3]

    for n in range(3, a, 2):
        if prime_test_list(n, known_primes):
            known_primes.append(n)

            m = 2 ** n - 1

            if lucas_lehmer_test(n, m):
                known_mersenne_primes.append(m)

    return known_mersenne_primes

print(mersenne_prime_print_list(100))
```

**OUTPUT**

[3, 7, 31, 127, 8191, 131071, 524287, 2147483647, 2305843009213693951, 618970019642690137449562111]

The `mersenne_prime_print_list(n)` function returns all the mersenne primes that have prime exponents of less than `n`.

Of the roughly 50 *known* Mersenne primes, the above code won't get you much past the 20th or so (`mersenne_prime_print_list(5000)`) before it becomes too inefficient.

As far as list comprehensions, they aren't needed, but feel free to rewrite the code to use them.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested it, but maybe this would work?

```
k = 1

while k<n:
    if( pow( 2, k) - 1 == n):
        print "This number is a mersenne prime"
        break
    if( pow( 2, k) >= n):
        print "This number is not a mersenne prime"
        break
    else:
        k+=1
```

It goes through all of the mersenne primes until it either finds a match with the given number or until the square gets bigger than the given number.

Comment: I need to find merssene unmbers. i need to write a function to print out mersenne prime numbers

Comment: @user59220 I'm not too sure what you mean. Your first function tests to see if n is a prime number, but now you're asking for a function that prints a list of mersenne primes? To my understanding, there are an infinite number of mersenne primes.

Comment: i want to print the first 13 numbers.

Comment: def prime_test_list(n,known_primes):
    k = 1
    stop_val = len(known_primes)
    if(n>2):
        while k<stop_val:
            cprime = known_primes[k]
            if n%cprime == 0:
                return 0            
            else:
                k+=1
        return 1
    else:
        return 1

Comment: then,  def prime_print_list(a):
    n = 2
    known_primes = [1] 
    while(n<a):
        val = prime_test_list(n,known_primes)
        if(val==1):
            known_primes.append(n)            
        n+=1
    print known_primes