# I am trying to filter out of a list for Mersenner prime but it is picking up empty values

Tags: python, filter

```
k=2
a=[]
while((((2**k)-1))<=upper):

    #using filter() to generate the list
    #in the form of 2^k-1
    result=filter(lambda x: x==((1<<k)-1),prime)
    a.append(list(result))
    k+=1
```

Please help me and let me know if I am doing anything wrong. I am currently new to Python so I do not have much knowledge.

Comment: What is in upper and prime?

Comment: Taking repeated passes over `prime`, one for each `k`, is inefficient. It is quite easy to check if something is a power of 2. As your predicate, write a custom function which checks if `p+1` is a power of 2 and then use it to filter your list just once.

Comment: @DSteman prime is my sequence of prime numbers and upper is the upper limit

Comment: @JohnColeman hey man can you please write a snippet of what you meant by it

Comment: You should provide the code which generated the primes to make this a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnColeman my rest of the code


`lower=int(input('Enter lower limit of a sequence: '))
upper=int(input('Enter upper limit of a sequence: '))
a=[]
#checking prime numbers within range
#list comprehension
prime = [x for x in range(2, upper) if all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2, x))]
#print(prime)
Mersenne(prime,upper)`

Answer (score 0):

Using efficient functions from here [Fastest way to list all primes below N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n) and here [Find Mersenne prime numbers using list comprehensions and my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756609/find-mersenne-prime-numbers-using-list-comprehensions-and-my-code) something like this could do the job. Where you can fill `upper` and `prime` with whatever you like.

```
def mersenne_test(n):

    k = 0
    m = 0
    while m<=n:
        m = 2**k-1
        if(n==m):
            return "This number is a Mersenne number since it is equal by to 2**%d-1" % k
        k += 1
    return "This number is not a Mersenne number."

def primes(n):
    """ Returns  a list of primes < n """
    sieve = [True] * n
    for i in range(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if sieve[i]:
            sieve[i*i::2*i]=[False]*((n-i*i-1)//(2*i)+1)
    return [2] + [i for i in range(3,n,2) if sieve[i]]

upper = 100
primes = primes(100)

for number in primes:
    print (mersenne_test(number))
```